# Where is type "object_t" defined, in C?

Tags: c, header-files

I'm a .NET programmer by day, and I'm learning C using Effective C by Robert Seacord.
I'm on Chapter 5 - Control Flow, where it describes "goto" and I'm trying to compile "Listing 5-11: Using a goto chain to release resources". But type "object_t" is not defined.
I assumed I could just find the definition in one of the standard headers (stdint.h etc.) but I can't find it and a Stack Overflow and Google search aren't helping.
I've searched this and previous chapters to no avail. Is this a user-defined type that the author doesn't explain, at this point? Or is my Googling that bad?

I've tried lots of header files I can think of:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

Here's the function definition:

```
int do_something(void) {
  FILE *file1, *file2;
  object_t *obj;
  int ret_val = 0; // Initially assume a successful return value

  file1 = fopen("a_file", "w");
  if (file1 == NULL) {
    ret_val = -1;
    goto FAIL_FILE1;
  }

  file2 = fopen("another_file", "w");
  if (file2 == NULL) {
    ret_val = -1;
    goto FAIL_FILE2;
  }

  obj = malloc(sizeof(object_t));
  if (obj == NULL) {
    ret_val = -1;
    goto FAIL_OBJ;
  }

  // Operate on allocated resources

  // Clean up everything
  free(obj);
FAIL_OBJ:  // Otherwise, close only the resources we opened
  fclose(file2);
FAIL_FILE2:
  fclose(file1);
FAIL_FILE1:
  return ret_val;
}
```

Here's the error: `error: unknown type name ‘object_t’`

Comment: It's worth noting that anything suffixed by `_t` is reserved for POSIX so you should avoid using that naming convention for your own objects in your own code

Comment: That's what I thought! This definitely confused me, because I believe this is mentioned in the book itself

Comment: Which is fair... the author probably should have used a `struct foo` or some such as that's generally the demonstration standard. If they have a place you can give feedback maybe it would be worth doing so, that way they can decide if they want to fix it in a later printing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no standard type called `object_t`.  It's a user defined type.

And given how this type is being used (i.e. just to demonstrate allocating memory), you can define it to be anything you want.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it . Dynamically allocating memory is the next chapter, so it will probably help to work through that first.

Comment: To put it another way, `object_t` is being used in the text as a kind of wildcard, meaning any (object) type you want can go there.  This uses the word "object" in the C language's sense of that term: a contiguous region of storage whose contents represent a value.  This is as opposed to a function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, thank you. I was initially thrown off because I thought that types suffixed with "_t" were reserved for standard library type definitions.